# Detect UI touch events in uniy3d............?

Tags: touch, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Presently working on mobile 3D endless runner game.when press UI button my player running animation.when touch on mobile scree my player attacking animation. But here my problem is when pressed UI button both running and attack animation is played.

can any one suggest how to solve this problem

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class TestAgain : MonoBehaviour
{
float lastTouchForDouble, lastTouchForMulti, presentTouchTime = 0.3f,multiTouchTime = 0.2f;
    bool isTouch;
    public GameObject ant;
    public float zoomValue;
    float deltaMagnitudeDiff;
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit  hit;
    public float scaleFactor;
    public float minScale = 0.05f;
    public  float maxScale = 1f;

    void Update ()//!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(pointerId)
    {   
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
                if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)){
                    return;
                }
                int pointerId = touch.fingerId;

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.touchCount != 2) {
                            if (!isTouch) {
                                isTouch = true;
                            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (touch.position);
                                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                                    if (hit.collider.name.Contains ("Player")) {
                                        // Player attack animation
                                    }
                                }
                            }

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        //Play run animation
    }
```

Comment: needs more info.. how does your scripts looks like for UI button running and touch attack? (sounds like you are taking touch.count>0 anywhere, which means it plays when you touch button also)

Comment: i attached my code please check it once  mgear

Comment: my problem is solved